# Excetpion handling in c++/cli

Tags: c++-cli

Actually i am working on c++/CLI dll which is using C# dll and c++/cli dll will use from native c.
**c++/cli code is like:-**

```
public ref class Class1
{
    // TODO: Add your methods for this class here.
public:
     static Managed_EMV_DLL::Managed_EMV ^obj = gcnew Managed_EMV(); // object of c#   class
     bool INIT_READER(unsigned int *);
     bool READ_KEY(unsigned int *ERROR_CODE,unsigned char *RETURN_ARRAY, unsigned int *Array_LENGTH);

};
```

-i want to handle the exception in c++/CLI code,
-handle exception when c# dll not found.
how i can make it.

Comment: You can't, the exception is not raised in your code.  It will occur in the client code, raised by the JIT compiler when it cannot compile the type initializer (aka static constructor) of your class.  Since the client code is C, that gives you a really hard time to catch and diagnose the exception.  Technically __try/__except is possible but you just don't know anything about the reason for the SEH exception.

Comment: What about wrapping the first referencing of Class1 into another type that exposes a public method, putting a try/catch in *that* method, and calling it from the client code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to handle any kind of exception not only FormatException or TypeInitializationException.
Here i write code like:-

```
try
{

}
catch (Exception^ ex) 
{ 
Console::WriteLine("Error in C++/CLI INIT function: {0}", ex->ToString());
} 
catch (...) 
{ 
      Console::WriteLine("Error in INIT");
}
```

and it works good.... i hope it will catch any kind of exception...

Answer (score 1):

What is the exact problem you're facing .... See the below example format.

```
try 
 {
 }
catch(FormatException ^) // display an appropriate message
 {
   Console::WriteLine(L"You must enter a valid number "
                               L"and no other character!");
 }
```

Just sort out what exception could be thrown from C# dll and then put appropriate handles in your C++/CLI code.